# Using GREP to format numbers which are succeeded by specific characters

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

Hi dear stackoverflow community,

I have a small GREP question and would need your help.
In my catalog, there are some ordering numbers which need specific formatting.

As you can see, the numbers are always bold and they also are colored when they are **preceded** by a "to ".
However, I want the two numbers **before** the " to" to be colored also.
I was not able to find out how this is done.
This is how they SHOULD look like using GREP. Basically the "00" is also colored.

[image: How it should be]

Right now, my GREP code looks like this.

```
(?<=\d\d)-\d\d(?=\sto)
```

On the right you can see that right now, the "00" in front of the "to" is not colored.

Does someone know why this is not working? :)

[image: This is how my GREP window looks like at the moment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the following three Grep patterns to the *Paragraph Style*:

- `(?<=[A-Z]{2}-)\d{4}-\d{2}` - Apply Character Style: **Bold** ([example](https://regex101.com/r/jMObzO/1)).
- `(?<=[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-)(\d{2})(?= to -??\d{2})` - Apply Character Style: **Bold-Color** ([example](https://regex101.com/r/jMObzO/2)).
- `(?<=[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{2} to )-??\d{2}` - Apply Character Style: **Bold-Color** ([example](https://regex101.com/r/jMObzO/3/)).

**Note:** The two different *Character Styles* used, namely **Bold**, and **Bold-Color**

---

#### *Paragraph Style Options* > *GREP Style*:

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it is working! Thank you so much! :)
I just have one question left, I sometimes have articles that look like this: AR-1234
Their numbers should also be bold. Is there a way to incorporate this into the code? I would try it myself, but frankly the code is too complex for me to understand :')

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: used this code instead `(?<=[A-Z]{2}-)\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{4}`

So thank you again, I think I learned a few things about GREP from you!